# jCarouselLite: Pause Scrolling on hover

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I'm using jCarouselLite and everythig is working fine.
However I want that the auto scrolling paused once I hover over the carousel.

The jCarouselLite doco is saying that I can use this:

```
$('div.carousel').trigger('pauseCarousel')
```

But I don't understand much about jQuery. How can I implement that pause function in the following code?:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() { 
    jQuery(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
        auto: 3000,
        speed: 1000,
        visible: 1,
        circular: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        responsive: true,
        vertical: true
   });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can chain the [`jQuery.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) function to your `jCarouselLite` object instantiation like this:

```
$('div.carousel').jCarouselLite({
  btnNext: '.next',
  btnPrev: '.prev',
  auto: 3,
  speed: 500
}).mouseover(function(){
  $(this).trigger('pauseCarousel');
});
```

Live demo available at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/agcv8hjb/). When you mouse-over the carousel, the horizontal scrolling will pause. On mouse leave, the scrolling will resume automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. The live demo doesn't work either.

Comment: It looks like the `http://plugins.learningjquery.com/jcarousellite/src/jquery.jcarousellite.js` file is not loading up properly on jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you tried updating your codes with my changes? The carousel should start scrolling horizontally. When your mouse over it, it will pause the scrolling, then resume on mouse-out. If you really want to see the fiddle works, you will have to navigate to the js file link I posted above, refresh your browser, so that your browser can cache the js.